# Snowflake Substring Concat Issue: Numeric value '' is not recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have a fiscal quarter column, and I want to add a column that displays the previous quarter in the same row.  I've done this successfully in tableau with logic like below.

```
IF RIGHT([current_qtr], 1) = "1"
THEN LEFT([current_qtr],2)+ STR(INT(MID([current_qtr], 3,2)) -1) +"Q4"
ELSE LEFT([current_qtr],5)+ STR(INT(RIGHT([current_qtr],1)) -1)
END
```

Example of expected output in snowflake

| current_qtr | previous_qtr | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY21Q1 | FY20Q4 | etc |
| FY21Q2 | FY21Q1 | etc |

When I try to do this in snowflake though I keep getting this "Numeric value '' is not recognized error instead.  Any ideas how to fix?  Below is what I attempted.

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
   WHEN SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,5,1) = 1 
      THEN SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,1,2) || TRY_CAST(SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,3,2) as INTEGER)-1 || 'Q4'
      ELSE SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,5,1) || TRY_CAST(SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,3,2) as INTEGER)-1
   End As prev_qtr
   FROM table as p
```

Answer (score 2):

This logic might look way better as a SQL UDF than as a big pile of strange SQL inside a query:

```sql
create or replace function prev_quarter_formatted(x string)
returns string
as
$$
(
    select 'FY' || to_varchar(prev_q, '%y') || 'Q' || quarter(prev_q)
    from (
        select substr(x, 3,2) year
            , (1+3*(substr(x, 6,1)::int-1)) q_to_month
            , to_date(year||'-'||q_to_month||'-01', 'yy-mm-dd') as_date
            , dateadd(month, -3, as_date) prev_q
    )
)
$$
;


select prev_quarter_formatted('FY21Q1') a
;
```

Notice that for the logic I transformed the quarter into a date, subtracted 3 months, and formatted again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtle differences in the syntax for casting. You can use your current CASE statement with some minor adjustments:

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
   WHEN SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,6,1) = '1' 
      THEN SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,1,2) || ((SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,3,2))::int - 1) || 'Q4'
      ELSE SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,1,2) || SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,3,2) || (SUBSTR(p.current_qtr,3,2)::int-1)
END AS prev_qtr
FROM table1 as p
```